# Create a many-to-many relationship in Core Data with Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, many-to-many

I'm working on a flash card app and want users to be able to have decks containing multiple cards and for cards to be assigned to multiple decks. For example, someone might create decks for "Michelangelo", "Leonardo Da Vinci" and "Galileo Galilei" each containing cards of their many works, but then they might have another deck called "Italian Renaissance" that contains all of those cards together.

How do I go about having this many-to-many relationship using Swift. I've tried to look around and it seems like the popular consensus is to rework the structure to only have one-to-many relationships but I don't believe it's possible for what I'm trying to achieve. Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## Approach:

Create `to many` relationships on both the relationships

## How to do it:

1. Create Entity `Card`
2. Create Entity `Deck`
3. On the Entity `Card`, create a relationship called `decks`. Let the destination be `Deck` and make it a`to many` relationship.
4. On the Entity `Deck`, create a relationship called `cards`. Let the destination be `Card` and select the **inverse** relationship as `decks`

**Note:** Ensure inverse relationships are properly set, this will be critical when you use them, as you have to just do 1 side of the relationship and core data will take care of the other side of the relationship.

I have just pasted 2 screenshots, hopefully it helps.

### Card Relationship:

[image]

### Deck Relationship:

[image]

### Code:

```
class LocalDataStorage {

    func test() {

        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)

        let card1 = Card(context: context)
        card1.title = "c1"

        let card2 = Card(context: context)
        card2.title = "c2"

        let deck1 = Deck(context: context)
        deck1.title = "d1"

        let deck2 = Deck(context: context)
        deck1.title = "d2"

        card1.decks = [deck1, deck2]
        card2.decks = [deck1]

        //Notice how the inverse relationships automatically work
        print("deck1.cards = \(String(describing: deck1.cards))") //2 elements
        print("deck2.cards = \(String(describing: deck2.cards))") //1 element
    }
}
```